# Default style for ReadOnly cells in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

The question is about standard .NET DataGridView control.
Is there a way to specify **once** some style for all ReadOnly cells so it will be **automatically** applied to all of them?
Please don't propose me to handle events - I believe it can be done using events.
I'm asking about **some DataGridView built-in technique** to do this.

I'd like style to include Bold font or different background color.
Thanks.

Comment: In WPF you can do it w/o events. Not so sure this is at all possible with a DGV.

Comment: In a winforms datagridview, there is no way to change the style automatically without using events.